# How to write Json null value as an empty line in new file (converting json based log into column format, i.e., one file per column)

Tags: python, json, file, file-handling, logfile

example of log file:

```
{"timestamp": "2022-01-14T00:12:21.000", "Field1": 10, "Field_Doc": {"f1": 0}}
{"timestamp": "2022-01-18T00:15:51.000", "Field_Doc": {"f1": 0, "f2": 1.7, "f3": 2}}
```

It will generate 5 files:

1.timestamp.column

2.Field1.column

3.Field_Doc.f1.column

4.Field_Doc.f2.column

5.Field_Doc.f3.column

Example content of timestamp.column:

```
2022-01-14T00:12:21.000
2022-01-18T00:15:51.000
```

I'm facing a problem while the values of keys are null, undefined as when the value us is null for example:

```
{"timestamp": "2022-01-14T00:12:21.000", "Field1": null, "Field_Doc": {"f1": undefined}}
```

can someone help me out here?

Comment: send your code please

Comment: You can check the code on this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194832/converting-json-based-log-into-column-format-i-e-one-file-per-column

Comment: so that link shows 3 different ways of doing it. Which one are you using? Also, questions *should* be self-contained. Thirdly, please provide a good example of what you actually want to achieve. From the question as is, I cannot determine what it is you want to happen when a `null` or `undefined` is encountered. Also, note that `null` is a valid JSON value, but `undefined` is not. Lastly, the input file is of type `ndjson` (just as an FYI)

Comment: the file is not a JSON file, it's mentioned in the heading itself, JSON-BASED LOGFILE. logfile are always text files, and I'm using the code mentioned in the last, and I have to convert that log file into a column file for each key.

Comment: I have a edge case that i'm stuck on which is:                                                                The column file format is as follows:
- string fields are separated by a new line '\n' character. Assume that no string value has 
   new line characters, so no need to worry about escaping them
- double, integer & boolean fields are represented as a single value per line
- null, undefined & empty strings are represented as an empty line

Comment: The first two are handled and fo the last one empty is handled, I'm stuck on the null and undefined one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the input file is actually an NDJSON. See [the docs](http://ndjson.org/).

That being said, since [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) already gave [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195529/9267296) on how to process the NDJSON logfile I'm going to skip that part. Do note that there's a library to deal with NDJSON files. [See PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/).

His code needs minimal adjustment to deal with the `undefined` edge case. The `null` value is a valid JSON value, so his code doesn't break on that.

You can fix this easily by a `string.replace()` while doing the `json.loads()` so it becomes valid JSON, and then you can check while writing if `value == None` to replace the value with an empty string. Note that `None` is the python equivalent of JSON's `null`.

Please note the inclusion of `:`  in the replace function, it's to prevent false negatives...

**main loop logic**

```py
for line in file_obj:
    # the replace function makes it valid JSON
    data = json.loads(line.replace(': undefined', ': null'))
    print(data)
    process_dict(data, write_func)
```

**write_func() function adjustment**

```py
def write_func(key, value):
    with open(key + '.column', "a") as f:
        # if the value == None, make it an empty string.
        if value == None:
            value = ''
        f.write(str(value) + "\n")
```

I used the following as the input string:

```
{"timestamp": "2022-01-14T00:12:21.000", "Field1": 10, "Field_Doc": {"f1": 0}}
{"timestamp": "2022-01-18T00:15:51.000", "Field_Doc": {"f1": 0, "f2": 1.7, "f3": 2}}
{"timestamp": "2022-01-14T00:12:21.000", "Field1": null, "Field_Doc": {"f1": undefined}}
```